# Override application properties spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have application.properties like

```
spring.mail.host=${MAIL_HOST:smtp.gmail.com}
spring.mail.port=${MAIL_PORT:587}
```

In test I want to change these properties, i run tests with profile like

```
mvn clean install -Ptests
```

Then I tried to override

```
mvn clean install -Ptests -DMAIL_HOST=host -DMAIL_PORT=123
```

but its not working for me. It is possible to do like this?

Comment: Do you mean `application.properties` dot instead of underscore?

Comment: I do not see any other problem except the filename.

Comment: @gtiwari333 yes, i meant dot, sorry

Comment: Use . Instead of_ and try again. As spring.mail....

Comment: Why don't you add in test profile all this properties

Comment: @Max, also confirm if you have application.properties under both main and test? If so, make sure to put the spring.mail* properties under test application.properties

Comment: @gladiator you are right i just forgot to add env_varibles in profile, my bad. Thank you guys for responses

Answer (score 0):

You add custom properties to application.yml / properties or application-{env}.yml / properties . Spring recognise it and you can access it via

@Value

Spring environment

Using Spring ConfigurationProperties